# Why do I keep getting an error: TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, t-test

```
stats.ttest_ind(med_df.dropna['age'], med_df.dropna['sex'], equal_var= True)
```

Trying to do a ttest on age and sex shown above but keep getting this error: TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable. What am I doing wrong?

I tried it like this:

```
stats.ttest_ind(med_df.dropna['age'], med_df.dropna['sex']
```

but I got the same error.

Comment: I'm guessing you probably meant to call `dropna()` and then index the result, e.g.: `med_df.dropna()['age']`.

Comment: now I am getting : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Your dataframe has strings in one of the columns where numbers are expected.

Comment: how do i test strings and integers together?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details including sample data. Anyway, you are doing a t-test in a wrong way. It's a test for a null hypothesis, where usually two populations on a same variable are compared.